# Firestore listener delayed when coming from background in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am running a simple function that queries an `orders` collection and adds a snapshot listener so it stays updated when there are changes to documents in the query.

It works perfectly fine in every situation, except for the case when a user locks their phone on `iOS` and comes back to the app.

In this case, when the user comes back to the app from the background, it takes about ~30 sec. for the listener to become active again and handle any changes.

Does anyone know why this may be happening? Does `iOS` have some sort of "wake-up" time when in app comes in from the background?

**Snapshot Listener Function:**

```
// function gets orders that are either in status "new" or "ready"
const getOrders = async () => {
  try {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("orders")
      .where("userId", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .where("status", "in", ["new", "ready"])
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        if (!snapshot.empty) {
          let ordersArr = [];
          snapshot.forEach((order) => {
            ordersArr.push({ id: order.id, data: order.data() });
          });
          setOrders(ordersArr);
        } else {
          setOrders(null);
        }
      });
  } catch (error) {
    alert("Error getting orders");
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you deactivate the listener when the app enters the background and reactivate it when the app reenters the foreground?

Comment: No I don't. Is that the issue?

Comment: More than likely. Unless your app is configured to run in the background, and really needs to, then the listeners shouldn't be listening and updating a UI that isn't rendered on screen. When the app reenters the foreground and you reactivate the listener, it will fire immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you think would be the best method to detach the listener when it enters the background/enable it when it comes to the foreground?

Comment: There are a number of ways to detect when the app enters the background. App-wide, you can use an app delegate method. View-controller specific, you can subscribe to the appropriate `NotificationCenter` notification, such as `UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this fixed it. Life saver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by detaching the Firestore listener when the app goes to the background [Detach a Listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener)

I was able to achieve this by using [Expo's AppState](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/appstate/)

Comment: How exactly did you achieve this whilst maintaining a cleanup unsubscribe function? I'm trying to do this but by conditionally subscribing when the app is active, this function cannot be recalled to unsubscribed. Also, it also needs to still detach when the component unmounts, so needs to be within useeffect still.

Comment: I was able to store the listener with the useRef() hook. That way I could unsubscribe it in the return function of useEffecf() AND in an AppState listener when the app retreats to the background. Hope this helps.